# How to apply logic in your Bootstrap code?

Tags: bootstrap-4, responsive-design, logic, responsive

I'm new to bootstrap, went through the documentation on bootstrap official site but after trying it by myself I find it difficult. None of my pages are responsive and I don't understand when to use **xl-lg-md-sm**.

What should we consider before using any of these.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please check the below explanation? Hope it will work for you.

In bootstrap 4 there are five default responsive tiers. These are the class prefix used to apply your style for responsive as per responsive tiers.

1. **xl** [.col-xl] - This class is used for extra large devices (which are greater than 1200px)

you can apply your style in this media query

```
@media only screen and (main-width:1200px){
//apply your style
}
```

2. **lg** [.col-lg] - This class is used for large devices (which are greater than 992px but less than 1200px)

you can apply your style in this media query

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) and (max-width:1199px){
//apply your style
}
```

3. **md** [.col-md] - This class is used for medium devices (which are greater than 768px but less than 992px)

you can apply your style in this media query for tablet device

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width:991px){
//apply your style
}
```

4. **sm** [.col-sm] - This class is used for small devices (which are greater than 576px but less than 768px)

you can apply your style in this media query for tablet device

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 576px) and (max-width:767px){
//apply your style
}
```

5. **xs** [.col-] - This class is used for small devices (which are less than 576px)

you can apply your style in this media query for an mobile device

```
@media only screen and (max-width:575px){
//apply your style
}
```

for more detailed information, please check the bootstrap grid system [topic](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/overview/)

Answer (score 1):

since you mentioned that your pages aren't responsive, make sure you remembered to add a viewport meta tag in the head of your pages, similar to below:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

Please see https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#starter-template for more details.

Comment: Yeah I used this tag what happens is a part of my page is responsive and some part is not. For example the table which I want to show is responsive but not my navbar. Do you have any good youtube channel so I can study from there without asking silly questions.

Comment: @UsamaBagwan, if you have a block on the page which isn't responsive and you've checked that the viewport meta tag is in place, the next thing you want to rule out are elements within this block which have pixel widths that are hard coded and are too wide. There's fantastic learning to be had on YouTube, I'm sure you'll find something  good if you search for CSS tutorials. Then the second thing you want to search for is web inspector tutorials so you can learn more about how to troubleshoot issues like this. Good luck!